How am I using Microsoft's dotnet-install.ps1 incorrectly
PowerShell 5.1
I'm trying to install .Net 8 SDK remotely via Invoke-Command (executing on Win 10 Pro to install on Windows Server 2022), but I'm getting some weird response. There's no SDK currently installed on my Windows Server 2022 and it's saying it's already installed.
rsexe1.ps1 (Windows 10 pro)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -Credential $credential {
  c:\temp\dotnet-install.ps1 -Version 8.0.300 | Out-Null
}

weird response - because it really didn't install it on my Windows Server 2022
PS C:\temp> .\rsexe1.ps1
dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK with version '8.0.300' is already installed.
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: "C:\Users\rsrem\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\". Note: This change will not be visible if PowerShell was run as a child process.
PS C:\temp>



and how are we supposed to help without having information about the error?

i guess it wasn't an error message vs a weird message (updated OP) but it says the sdk was installed but it really wasn't. When I use dotnet --list-sdks no sdks are listed.

Now if i use Enter-PSSession it behaves as expected and it really does install it, smh using  just dotnet-install.ps1 -Version 8.0.300

I take that back, Enter-PSSession didn't work. it says it installed it but didn't really.

8.0.300 [C:\program files\dotnet\sdk]```

How are you confirming whether it's installed / not installed after running your script?

dotnet --list-sdks and looking in the Control Panel under Programs
